# Как создать новый request запрос для axios из запроса который пришёл на сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

## У меня есть два сервера и клиент.

- Серверы написанны на `Node js` с использованием `express`
- `Сервер №1` получает запрос от `клиента` на соединение.
- `Сервер №1` должен с помошью модуля `axios` передать этот запрос на `сервер №2`

> Проксирование запроса в данном случае не подходит, потому что `Сервер №2`  сразу же отдаёт ответ и закрывает соединение. А мне надо что бы соединение `клиента` с `сервером №1` не закрывалось.

### Пример кода

```
app.get('/*', async (req, res) => {
   await axios({ ??? req ??? }) 
})
```

Как можно сделать клон request - a запроса с `сервера №1` и передать его на `сервер №2` ?

Comment: Каким образом клон запроса поможет держать соединение ? Там же есть заголовок keep-alive, но его именно выставить нужно, а не просто запрос копировать

Comment: Про keep-alive не знал. Спасибо. Сегодня прочитаю что это такое. Это не полная схема, я объект ответа сохраняю и его потом использую. я вчера сделал что хотел.